# Using touchmove to trigger hover event

Tags: javascript, html, css, mobile, shopify

I'm relatively new to coding and am running into a particular issue with my website. My homepage has images on it with overlay text hover effect that occurs when a cursor is moved over the image. It works perfectly on desktop, however, not on mobile. I would like for the hover text to appear when the user swipes across the image in any direction. I've done some research and it appears that I should somehow be using jQuery and the touchmove function to make this happen. But I just can't figure it out. I am using Shopify (debut theme) to build my website. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Here's my CSS for hover event:

```
//hover effect//
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.image {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 99%;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: .5s ease;
  background-color: #000000;
}

.container:hover .overlay {
  opacity: 0.7;
}

.text {
  color: white;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
  white-space: pre;
}
```

Thanks!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd need to apply a class with the desired effect to the target element. 
You could do it with Jquery, but javascript is perfectly capable to do it on its own.
Something like:

Javascript:

```
const myTargetElement = document.getElementsByClassName('overlay')[0]; // index to be confirmed

// add hover style
myTargetElement.addEventListener('touchmove', function (e) {
    e.target.classList.add('hover'); // or whichever class name you'd like
});
// remove hover style on end
myTargetElement.addEventListener('touchend', function (e) {
    e.target.classList.remove('hover'); // or whichever class name you'd like
});
```

CSS:

```
.container:hover .overlay,
.overlay.hover {
   opacity: 0.7;
}
```

Note: if you want to target all the elements `.overlay` on your page with that code, you would need something like:

Javascript:

```
const myTargetElements = document.getElementsByClassName('overlay');

// convert HTML collection to array
const myTargetElementsArray = [].slice.call(myTargetElements);
myTargetElementsArray.forEach(function (element) {

    // add hover style
    element.addEventListener('touchmove', function (e) {
        e.target.classList.add('hover'); // or whichever class name you'd like
    });

    // remove hover style on end
    element.addEventListener('touchend', function (e) {
        e.target.classList.remove('hover'); // or whichever class name you'd like
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply! Do you have any idea as to how I would implement this in shopfiy? As in, would I just copy and paste your last box of code? If so, into which asset? (theme.scss.liquid, theme.js, vendor.js, etc?)

Comment: EDIT: Hey, you're actually amazing! For others experiencing a similar issue, I pasted the code into theme.js. Moustacheiste had some syntax errors (missed couple of brackets) so find the "fixed" code below! 

Thanks again man!

Comment: thanks, happy it solved your issue. Sorry about the missing quote indeed, I edited the code. I couldn't figure out why the syntax highlighting was crap... :joy:

Answer (score 0):

so Moustachiste's code works! It had a few syntax errors but I was able to resolve them quickly. Here's the final version:

```
const myTargetElements = document.getElementsByClassName('overlay');

// convert HTML collection to array
const myTargetElementsArray = [].slice.call(myTargetElements);
myTargetElementsArray.forEach(function (element) {

    // add hover style
    element.addEventListener('touchmove', function (e) {
        e.target.classList.add('hover'); // or whichever class name you'd like
    });

    // remove hover style on end
    element.addEventListener('touchend', function (e) {
        e.target.classList.remove('hover'); // or whichever class name you'd like
    });
    });
```

Paste the code into your theme.js and adjust the variable names accordingly. Should work for everyone!

Cheers to this guy!